# Memory leak with a memory stream

Tags: c#

I know this code is far from perfect but in my case this was the only
 way to do it correctly because im embedding WPF in C#, and when
 applying text regulary the Spellcheck does not work correctly

So this is my code:

```
RichTextBox temphotfix = new RichTextBox();
temphotfix.Font = new Font(temphotfix.Font.Name, 14);
System.Windows.Documents.TextRange range = new System.Windows.Documents.TextRange(omschrijving.Document.ContentStart, omschrijving.Document.ContentEnd);
temphotfix.Text = oms;
string temp = temphotfix.Rtf;
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(temp);
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
range.Load(stream, DataFormats.Rtf);
range = null;
temp = null;
byteArray = null;
temphotfix.Dispose();
stream.Dispose();
```

I stress tested this, and it seems like ever about 5 times the script gets ran, it adds about 1 MB ram.

What am i doing wrong, i litterly made everyting i used null, or desposed them.

Comment: Garbage Collection isn't going to happen when you set things to `null` or call `Dispose`.  It runs when it deems the memory pressure requires it.

Comment: The good news is that with 4GB free RAM, you can afford run this about 20,000 times before running out of memory. So see what happens when you run it 1,000,000 times - and if you run out of memory then, you've got a problem.

Comment: you can use `Using` block to decorate the `MemoryStream` or as well on `RichTextBox` that will help this object gets deallocated as soon as it comes out of scope, instead of calling `Dispose`.

Comment: **Use a memory profiler to diagnose memory problems**.

Comment: Youd did _not_ stress test this. That would have ended with an OOM exception or (more likely) with an Ok.

Answer (score -1):

As I told above in comment you can `using`, you can try this code. hope this should help.

```
    using (RichTextBox temphotfix = new RichTextBox())
    {
        temphotfix.Font = new Font(temphotfix.Font.Name, 14);
        System.Windows.Documents.TextRange range = new System.Windows.Documents.TextRange(omschrijving.Document.ContentStart, omschrijving.Document.ContentEnd);
        temphotfix.Text = oms;
        string temp = temphotfix.Rtf;
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(temp);
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray))
        {
            range.Load(stream, DataFormats.Rtf);
        }
        range = null;
        temp = null;
        byteArray = null;
        //temphotfix.Dispose();
        //stream.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: I did not fix it, but i tink it does help a little bit.